# Is there any way to "Find Usages" of Mirth Code Templates?

Tags: javascript, mirth

I inherited a big ugly integration with 70 channels. Many are no longer used but the ones that are used do cause some issues. I'm reviewing the code templates to see what I can get rid of and what's actually being used.

Any ideas how to do this efficiently?  Currently I just export the big XML and text search it.

TIA

Comment: Unfortunately, I think exporting the backup xml and text searching may be the only way to go about your task.